# Conditionally include sidebar and header in Angular App

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, angular-ng-if

On certain views I want a sidebar and header, and some I do not. Using AngularJS, what is the best approach to achieve this.

My current solution in mind is to use ng-if on the sidebar and header DIV, and in my Controllers, set a $scope variable to be set to true or false depending on the views I want the sidebar and header to appear.

A concrete example would be Youtube.com. On Youtube's homepage, notice there is a sidebar and a sub-header with the filters: "What to Watch" and "Music" in it. However, on any video page, the sidebar and sub-header doesn't exist. I want to achieve that in AngularJS.

**index.html**

```
    <html ng-app="demoApp">

    <body ng-controller="demoAppMainController">

        <header>
            <ng-include src="'./partials/mainHeader.html'"></ng-include>
            <ng-include ng-if="showSubHeader" src="'./partials/mainSubHeader.html'"></ng-include>
        </header>

        <main>
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </main>


    </body>
    </html>
```

**discussionBoard.html**

```
    <div class="discussionBoard" ng-controller="DiscussionBoardController">
         <h2>DiscussionBoard</h2>
    </div>
```

**controllers.js**

```
    var demoAppControllers = angular.module('demoAppControllers', []);

    demoAppControllers.controller('demoAppMainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.showSubHeader = true;
    }]);

    opinionLensControllers.controller('DiscussionBoardController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.showSubHeader = false;
    }]);
```

Comment: What you have tried? Post whatever you did we are here to help you in that,

Comment: I added my code. My first idea was to add `ng-if="showSubHeader"` to the ng-include directive, and in the DiscussionBoardController set `$scope.showSubHeader = false`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing it in `controller` level, I would configure that in `route` level. And will listen to the `$routeChangeSuccess` event and update the `$rootScope`.

```
demoAppControllers.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
        showHeader : true
    }).
    when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'discuss.html',
        controller: 'DiscussionBoardController',
        showHeader : false
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
}).
run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, next, current) {
        $rootScope.showHeader = next.$$route.showHeader;
    });
}]);
```

In your templates, you can just use `ng-if="showHeader"`. It will be easily maintainable I feel.

Comment: This throws a $injector:unpr error. I included $ngRoute:
`var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute', 'demoAppControllers']);`

Comment: It means that there is error injecting the dependencies. Make sure you include all necessary dependencies

Comment: $rootScope.showHeader is undefined. Angular must no recognize showHeaer as a key in routesProvider object.

Comment: Cool. Hope it's because of differences in angular version. but glad it worked for you :)

Comment: I figured it out. `next.$route.showHeader` should be `next.$$route.showHeader`. I also needed to include $routeScope in each controller in my controllers.js file.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. You saved my lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

ng-if="showHeader == true" use like this

```
 <ng-include ng-if="showHeader == true" src="'./partials/mainSubHeader.html'"></ng-include>
```

Comment: It's not required. `ng-if` will evaluate the expression for truthy value. So no need to do it explicitly